# Check for duplicated in gae datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm creating an Entity for every add command that I input but I want to know that how can I check for duplicates in the datastore?

```
    Entity entity = new Entity("Animal");
    entity.setProperty("nameOfAnimal",name_of_animal);
```

I want to check is if for the second time there is an animal which is entered with the same name, how do I check for a duplicate entry?

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options depending on what behaviour you are looking for.

If you use your `nameOfAnimal` as the entity's name, you can simply try fetching the entity by key before you create a new one:

```
Key animalKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Animal", "fox");
Entity fox;
try {
    fox = datastoreService.get(animalKey);
    // no exception thrown so fox already exists
    throw new RuntimeException("Animal already exists!");
}
catch(EntityNotFoundException e) {
    // no duplicates, so can create
    fox = new Entity(animalKey);
    fox.setNoise("unknown");
    datastoreService.put(fox);
}
```

If you're not using the nameOfAnimal as the key, you can use a `Query("Animal")` instead of the `get()` (as in the answer from *eluleci*).

Either way, beware there's a potential race condition there.  If you want to make it safe, you'll need to wrap it in a [transaction](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions), otherwise you may find two threads competing to create the first fox (for example), with one potentially overwriting the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can get try to get the entities by filtering the "nameOfAnimal" property and check the returned result. If the result is empty it means there is no entity yet.

```
Filter propertyFilter =
  new FilterPredicate("nameOfAnimal", FilterOperator.EQUAL, name_of_animal);
Query q = new Query("Animal").setFilter(propertyFilter);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
List<Animal> resultList = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));
if(resultList.size() > 0) {
    // same name exists
} else {
    // first entitiy with this name
}
```

The code is not tested but this is the main idea. [Here is the documentation for property filters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Property_filters).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the name of the animal as 'id' of the entity , and then use get by id to check whether this animal name exists or not.